# creating a csv file adds extra line while creating an ini file does not?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, ini

I tried to create first a csv file then create a ini file from the csv file I created. The issue is, when I parse the ini file it throws error. I checked the csv file (record from database), there is an extra line at the bottom. But when I create an ini file directly from database, there is no extra line at the bottom.

Additional Info: 
1. the error is thrown on this line: print_r($ini_array);
2. error: Getting this error message: “syntax error, unexpected '='”

This is how I create the CSV file:

```
$this->load->helper('csv');
                $this->db->select('*'); 
                $this->db->where('listing_id', $listingId);
                $query = $this->db->get('listing');

            //folder creation
                if (!is_dir('/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings')) {
                    mkdir('/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings', 0777, TRUE);
                }

                //file creation
                $file='/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/'.$listingId.'.csv';
                if(file_exists($file)){
                    unlink($file);
                }

                $this->load->helper('csv');
                $this->load->dbutil();
                $datas = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
                $this->load->helper('file');
                if ( ! write_file($file, $datas, 'a+b'))
                {
                    error_log('Unable to write the file');
                }
                else
                {
                    error_log('File written!');
                }
```

This is how I create the ini file (record from CSV):

```
$fileName = '/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/'.$listingId.'.csv';
            $fp = fopen($fileName, 'r');
            $fields = fgetcsv($fp); 

            $result = array();

            while ($record = fgetcsv($fp))
            {
                $result[] = array_combine($fields, $record);
            }

            $sess_array = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $sess_array = array(
                    'current_listing_id' => $row['listing_id'],
                    'listing_description' =>$row['description'],
                    'current_listing_min_age' => $row['min_age'],
                    'current_listing_max_age' => $row['max_age'],
                    'current_listing_contact_id' => $row['contact_id']
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
            }

            $this->write_ini_file($result, '/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/'.$listingId.'.ini', true);
            chmod("/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/$listingId.ini", 0775);
            $ini_array = parse_ini_file("/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/$listingId.ini", false);
            print_r($ini_array);
```

THis is how I create ini file directly from database:

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
            $this->db->where('listing_id', $listingId);
            $query = $this->db->get('listing');
            $results = $query->result();


             $file='/home/clemjon/Desktop/testListings/'.$listingId.'.ini';
                if(file_exists($file)){
                    unlink($file);
                }
            $this->write_ini_file($results, $file, true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just count total number of lines you have and subtract 1 from it.

If you have 1 to N lines in CSV. Then parse only 1 to (N-1)

Comment: but why it adds one line in csv and in ini does not?